# Active class added to a wrong document object in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my JS code which add an active class to the parent of all `<a>` objects which contain a href path who match with my current URL.

```
aObj = document.getElementById('menuG').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) {
        if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
            alert("Button n°"+i+" - Value : "+document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href));
            aObj[i].parentElement.className='active';
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the first button which have `href="/"` is always active.
The code `document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)` always return 0 for the first button and i don't understand why.

Here is my html code :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menuG">
    <li><a href="/">Mes Fichiers</a></li>
    <li><a href="historique.html">Historique</a></li>
    <li><a href="profil.html">Profil</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any URL will most likely contain the `/` of that first link tag. If you use `indexOf()`, it will find the `/` in any page of your website. Hence, that first link's parent will always get styled.

You can test it for yourself in the console of your browser. In an HTTPS website, the first match of `/` is in position 6 (7th character in a URL). `indexOf` just returns the position of the first match, and the `/` that's the `href` of your first link will always get a match.

You could replace the `href` of the first link with something like `index.html`, and then force a redirect from `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/index.html`. Your other bet is to change the way you check if this is the current page, by, for example, checking if `window.location.href` is strictly equal (`===`) to the `href` of a link tag: `window.location.href === aObj[i].href`.

Comment: Thanks for all. I understand how indexof() work now. And your solution work great ! Thank you !

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. Just don't forget that now you're looking for an exact match, so `example.com/index` won't match that first element. This would happen in case you decide to change the URL of your home page, but don't update the link tag (which would make sense if you do a 302 redirect, for example).